# trying to get image using fetch, the image is stored in firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Hy,
I am trying to get the image using fetch API, the URL is valid, as it works when I put the image URL in the Img tag.

my fetch function:

```
   getImage = () => {  
   const url= "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alpha-c790f.appspot.com/o/images%2Frivers.jpg?alt=media&token=6a96d672-23c1-425f-bdca-47f6d73608f0"


fetch(this.state.url,{
  mode: 'no-cors'
}).then(response => response.blob())
.then((res)=>{
     console.log(res);
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = objectURL;

}).catch(err=>{
  console.log(err);
})
}
```

the firebase cloud storage access rules :

```
      rules_version = '2';
      service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
           match /{allPaths=**} {
           allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
           }
        }
    }
```

I want to implement it like this because I want to put a spinner on it until the image comes

The response I get is this

```
           Blob {size: 0, type: ""}
                 size: 0
                 type: ""
            __proto__: Blob
```

Comment: Security rules don't have any effect on download URLs.  But I don't understand why you need to call fetch to get a URL to a file where you already have the URL.

Comment: the url is an image and i am trying to get the image

Comment: But the image already exists at that url, just add the url to your src on your image tag. No fetch required. Please edit your question to include the problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fetch an image, the image already exists at this url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alpha-c790f.appspot.com/o/images%2Frivers.jpg?alt=media&token=6a96d672-23c1-425f-bdca-47f6d73608f0

```
<img src='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alpha-c790f.appspot.com/o/images%2Frivers.jpg?alt=media&token=6a96d672-23c1-425f-bdca-47f6d73608f0'/>
```

If you would like to construct the image procedurally you can also do:

```
var newImgage = new Image() 
newImgage.src = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alpha-c790f.appspot.com/o/images%2Frivers.jpg'
```

Comment: This is correct but can you show the code of how to add the url to the src on the image tag? It would be a more complete answer.

Comment: yea I know about that. you can do var img = new Image() and then maybe img.src = link

Comment: @jay I wasn't really sure how to answer it in the context of the question since my answer invalidates the question. Are you asking me to show how to build an image procedurally? I can answer that but I feel like I would be answering a different question then. I've added paramveer's approach just for good measure.